# HTML Iframe get src with php

Tags: php, html, url, iframe, src

I have an webpage where I want to have another html page displayed. I used iframes. The page gets to know what to load is via the get procedure. But there is an fault in this coding I think...

```
            <iframe src="
            <?
            $file       = ($_GET['ti'])

            if ($title = '')
                echo "information.html";
                else echo "$file";
            ?>
            "></iframe>
```

The url the page would recieve looks like this:
http://www.website.com/reference.html?ti=unlimited.html

Comment: On a side note, depending on when you're setting your PHP variable you might be having a server/client side scripting issue, meaning you might need use some JavaScript (probably jQuery) to do a AJAX script to change the `src` attribute.

Comment: what is happening and what are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

It's your if / else syntax and over all php code.  It's not very well written.

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['ti'];

if ($title = '') {
     echo "information.html";
} else { 
     echo "$file";
}

?>
```

Comment: Yes the code is not written well but the If/Else is not the 'issue'. You do not need brackets if one line follows. Yes it's a good practice, but not needed.

Comment: With out the braces the `if` will only execute the immidately after it ignoring the `else` statement.  At least thats my understanding.

Comment: Yes the `if` statement will execute the next statement, but the `else` is still considered even without braces. [Example](http://codepad.org/YJlSmaa1)

Comment: See what you're saying. Still makes my eyes hurt reading it :(

Answer (score 1):

Need semicolon:

```
        $file       = ($_GET['ti']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [empty()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), like this:

```
    <iframe src="
    <?
    $file       = ($_GET['ti'])

    if (empty($title))
        echo "information.html";
        else echo $file;
    ?>
    "></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $possible = array("information.html", "home.html", "test.html");
    $file = isset($_GET['ti']) && 
            in_array($_GET['ti'], $possible)? $_GET['ti'] : "information.html";
?>
<iframe src="<?php echo $file;?>"></iframe>
```